# Gson com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Begin Type incorrect

Tags: android, gson

I am trying to read data from my blog. My JSON is starting with `{..` but Gson is not storing it in my `rssObject`. It throws `BEGIN_ARRAY Expected`.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    mdialog.dismiss();
    Log.d("gson object-----",s+"");

    rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s,RSSObject.class);
    // here I am using object but gson expect array, my json starts with 
    //  curl-braces "{" but why this error?
    Log.d("gson object-----",rssObject+"");
    FeedAdapter feedAdapter = new 
    FeedAdapter(rssObject,getBaseContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
    recyclerView.invalidate();
    feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

//my RSSObject class
        public class RSSObject
    {
        public String status;
        public Feed feed;
        public List items;

```
    public RSSObject(String status, Feed feed, List<Item> items) {
        this.status = status;
        this.feed = feed;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Feed getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setFeed(Feed feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Comment: post `RSSObject.class`

Comment: public class RSSObject
    {
        public String status;
        public Feed feed;
        public List<Item> items;

        public RSSObject(String status, Feed feed, List<Item> items) {
            this.status = status;
            this.feed = feed;
            this.items = items;
        }

        // here there are getters and setters
    }

Comment: share your JSON data.

Comment: https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Fitzmydarz.blogspot.in%2Fatom.xml

Comment: your api contains html contents. simple json string should be sent via api

Comment: it is my blog's xml converted to Json, i don't know  what to do. it is working fine for this https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmjmohiddin.com%2Fatom.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your item array some of enclosure is array and some of object look at 4 item. it should be same for all item either json object or json array

> "enclosure": {
>           "thumbnail": "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1OScwyF67RI/UbGu42S52AI/AAAAAAAAAME/OZgbtgNI8dc/s72-c/lonly.jpeg"
>         }

While in other item

> "enclosure": [],

Comment: oh.. may i know how can i solve this? what is the best way to get json data for a blog?

Comment: You make to same type for all either make it json array or json object so you need to change yoyur json response